# Self referencing class error "Multiplicity is not valid in Role ..."

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In order to trace and claim users changes in my web application, I built a class Claim from which every class of the app inherits.

The Claim class references User class two times:

1. reference to the user who created the record
2. reference to the user who as lastly modified the data of the record

The User class also inherit from Claim class.

I get this error:

> User_LastChangedBy_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'User_LastChangedBy_Target' in relationship 'User_LastChangedBy'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'

In order to simplify the problem I made a test project having a single class User that references itself two times.

If I create the class User with only a single self-reference, it works.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace TestEF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyContext db = new MyContext();

            User u = new User();
            u.Name = "John Doe";
            u.IdCreate = 1;
            u.IdEdit = 1;

            db.Users.Add(u);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    [Table("test_users")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
        public int IdCreate { get; set; }
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LastlyChangedBy")]
        public int IdEdit { get; set; }
        public User LastlyChangedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public MyContext() : base("Data Source=192.168.5.251,1433;User ID=sa;pwd=XXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=mywebapp") {
            //Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make it work ? What I mistake in my code ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need the whole User object for createdBy, lastchangedby? if its for a database just save the username in a string

Comment: It could be a workaround.Better it could be mark CreateBy and LastlyChangedBy as NotMapped and load them manually but I think that my initial idea should work, and I'm sure there is a solution to my problem, but I'm not a EF guru.

Comment: The foreign key properties must be nullable. Otherwise you can't insert a user when there are no users to refer to.

Comment: The foreign key mustn't be nullable. The initialization issue you are pointing out is simply resolved creating two built-in users "SYSTEM" Self-referenced and "Admin" that references to "SYSTEM".

Answer (score 0):

You are using the idea of TPT between `User` and `Claim` unless `Claim` is an abstract class and not generated in the DB.

To make your code work without any problem. I urge you to create a junction table between the `Claims` and `Users`.So, your code should look like this:

**Claims**

```
public class Claim
{
     // your code goes here
}
```

**Users**

```
public class User: Claim
{
      // your code goes here
}
```

**UserActions**

```
public class UserAction
{ 
       public int Id{get;set;}
       public int UserId{get;set;}
       public int ClaimId{get;set;}
       public DateTime CreatedOn{get;set;}
       public ActionType Action{get;set;}

       public User User{get; set;}
       public Claim Claim{get;set;}
}
```

This class will hold the `UserId` and `ClaimId` to trace all the logs in a normalized way.

**ActionType**

```
public enum ActionType
{
     Added=1,
     Modified=2
}
```

This structure will make your data more normalized and neat.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Monah. Yes, the Claim class is abstract. My model is TPH. Don't focus on my web app, focus on the code I submitted: "Class User have to reference to itself two times". How can this be achieved ?